# How to include extern env.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, git-workflow

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre
COPY build/libs/project-lion-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

My Spring `resources` directory contains:

../src/../resources in ..

```
application.yml
application-dev.yml
application-test.yml
env.properties <-- git ignore
```

This env file contains sensitive information, such as database passwords. So the file is not uploaded to Git.

However, the server does not work because the `env.properties` file was not found after docker deploy. How do I include `env.properties`?

Comment: why don't you ship the env.properties into your app.jar?

Comment: If you've placed the file in src/main/resources, by default it will be packaged into the JAR. You can confirm this is happening by [unpacking the JAR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html). If you see it there, then however you are _loading_ that file is likely to be the problem (that would be helpful information to include in the question).